# Access passing a varible to a text box

Tags: forms, variables, ms-access, vba

So I am still new to using Access and trying to get a variable to pass from one form to other.

Basically i have a Form (MainForm) that asks about five questions using toggle buttons.

Based on your answers you will then be pushed to one of 4 different new forms `(Level 1, Level 2, Level 3,Level 4)`.

With a text box in each of those forms.  I want the answers to the questions to be carried over into a multi line text box.

**I have been able to create a string variable that has a multi line message, but it will not carry over to the next form.**

here is a basic example of what i'm looking for:

**(Main Form)**

'previous code to gather questions and determine which Level it goes to.

```
CopyAll = "Do you like birthday cake? " & Quest1A & vbcrl _
        & "What which is your favorite color? " & Quest2A
```

[here is where i need to take "CopyAll" and move it to a text box of the other forms based on which level.]

any help would be great, like i said i am still new, but trying to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Use global variables

```
Public Quest1A as string

Sub MyFormButton.Onclick(
Quest1A = me.WhateverText.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you **open a form** you can pass a variable to the end of the command (as the `Arguments parameter`).

Then in each `Form's Open` event, you can process and validate the arguments passed to the form by looking at `Me.OpenArgs`

You can then assign it directly to your text box using 
`mytextbox.Value = Me.OpenArgs`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of a textbox from the main form event.

```
Docmd.Open acForm, "Level 1"  
Forms![Level 1].mytextbox = CopyAll
```

Or you can use a global variable defined in a module, or a macro variable, or  a table to store & read it.